# How to get the current day in flutter?

Tags: function, date, flutter, dart, dayofweek

I want to get the current day using dart.

Code I want:-

```
//I want something like this

var day = DateTime.getCurrentDay();
```

Output:-

```
Tuesday
```

Answer (score 9):

use this pattern

```
DateFormat('EEEE').format(yourDate);
```

or

```
DateFormat('EEEE').format(DateTime.now());
```

See all available patterns here

```
ICU Name                   Skeleton
 --------                   --------
 DAY                          d
 ABBR_WEEKDAY                 E
 WEEKDAY                      EEEE
 ABBR_STANDALONE_MONTH        LLL
 STANDALONE_MONTH             LLLL
 NUM_MONTH                    M
 NUM_MONTH_DAY                Md
 NUM_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY        MEd
 ABBR_MONTH                   MMM
 ABBR_MONTH_DAY               MMMd
 ABBR_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY       MMMEd
 MONTH                        MMMM
 MONTH_DAY                    MMMMd
 MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY            MMMMEEEEd
 ABBR_QUARTER                 QQQ
 QUARTER                      QQQQ
 YEAR                         y
 YEAR_NUM_MONTH               yM
 YEAR_NUM_MONTH_DAY           yMd
 YEAR_NUM_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY   yMEd
 YEAR_ABBR_MONTH              yMMM
 YEAR_ABBR_MONTH_DAY          yMMMd
 YEAR_ABBR_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY  yMMMEd
 YEAR_MONTH                   yMMMM
 YEAR_MONTH_DAY               yMMMMd
 YEAR_MONTH_WEEKDAY_DAY       yMMMMEEEEd
 YEAR_ABBR_QUARTER            yQQQ
 YEAR_QUARTER                 yQQQQ
 HOUR24                       H
 HOUR24_MINUTE                Hm
 HOUR24_MINUTE_SECOND         Hms
 HOUR                         j
 HOUR_MINUTE                  jm
 HOUR_MINUTE_SECOND           jms
 HOUR_MINUTE_GENERIC_TZ       jmv   (not yet implemented)
 HOUR_MINUTE_TZ               jmz   (not yet implemented)
 HOUR_GENERIC_TZ              jv    (not yet implemented)
 HOUR_TZ                      jz    (not yet implemented)
 MINUTE                       m
 MINUTE_SECOND                ms
 SECOND                       s
```

Answer (score 3):

```
// DateTime.now() or any DateTime format can be used.
DateFormat('EEEE').format(DateTime.now());
```

To use other Date formats/patterns like **"EEEE"** you can visit the [Official Documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/DateFormat-class.html)